# Could not find function "pred_to_fraction"

Tags: r, rscript

I am running an R script given from a professor to do correlation. But there is an error: could not find function "pred_to_fraction"．Does anyone know how to install this function? Which package is this function from? Thanks

Comment: Could you not ask your professor where the function is from?

Comment: An unfamilar professor, and don't get reply yet...

Comment: "Your search - "pred_to_fraction" r - did not match any documents.". Probably not from a publicly available package. There is probably another script somewhere that loads that function.

Comment: There is no base R function by that name and there doesn't appear to be function with that name in any R package published on CRAN (You can search all packages at https://rdrr.io/). The professor must have written that function themselves. There's no really anything we can do to help. You need to contact them.